# How can I use my action and programmatically transition to a view controller as defined in the storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue, uistoryboard

I have a sent Action, as follows:

```
    @IBAction func showSettings(sender: AnyObject) {
     let settingsPicker = SettingsViewController()
     settingsPicker.setDelegate(self)
     let navigationController = UINavigationController (rootViewController: settingsPicker)
     self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)  
     }
```

The method creates a controller, sets a reference to the delegate, and creates a navigation controller.

All this works, however the widgets defined in the story board do not appear. The SettingsViewController should manage a ui which is defined in a story board. I presume becuase I create it programmatically none of the widgets appear. The SettingsViewController does not programmatically create widgets, the are declaratively defined in the story board.

If I link (in the storyboard) the two controllers with a segue, then the widgets appear, but my action is not being used.

How can I use my action and present the view controller / ui as defined in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke a segue through code, see Laffen's answer.

If you want to create a view controller that's defined in your storyboard and then display it programmatically, use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to create a new instance of your view controller, then display it to the screen as desired (present it modally, push it onto your navigation stack, or whatever you want to do.)

Comment: In addition, the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method is available via the storyboard member : `self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("settings")`

Answer (score 2):

When you create a segue between your UIViewControllers, you should define an identifier, eg: "settingsSegue".

In your code you can then perform that segue by calling the segue with the identifier:

```
@IBAction func showSetting(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("settingsSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

To set up the SettingsViewController you should implement the following:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if let settingsController = segue.destinationViewController as? SettingsViewController {
        settingsController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

[Interacting with Storyboard and Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW82)